# Atlassian.NET SDK Async Methods don't throw Exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await

Edit:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 string summary = "TestSummary";
 string description = "TestDescription";
 string type = "Task";
 string projectKey = "TST";
 string priority = "p - 3";

 var issueCreated = createIssueWrapper(summary, description, type, priority, projectKey).Result;
}

public async Task <string> createIssueWrapper(string summary, string description, string type, string priority, string projectKey) {
 string returnVal = "";

 returnVal = await createIssue(summary, description, type, priority, projectKey);

 return returnVal;

}

public async Task <string> createIssue(string summary, string description, string type, string priority, string projectKey) {
 string returnVal = "";

 try {
  var issue = jira.CreateIssue(projectKey);
  issue.Type = type;
  issue.Priority = priority;
  issue.Summary = summary;
  issue.Description = description;

  var jiraIssue = await issue.SaveChangesAsync();

  if (jiraIssue != null) {
   returnVal = jiraIssue.Key.ToString();
  }

 } 
 catch (Exception ex) {
  returnVal = "There was a problem creating the issue. Please try again.";
 }

 return returnVal;

}
```

---

I've been trying to figure out why Atlassian.NET Jira async methods aren't returning exceptions like their regular (non-async) methods.

As an example, I call an async method `createIssue` to create a new Jira issue, like this:

```
string summary = "TestIssue";
string description = "TestDescription";
string type = "Task";
string projectKey = "TST";
string priority = "p - 3";

Task<string> created = createIssue(summary, description, type, priority, projectKey);
```

Here is the async method:

```
public async Task<string> createIssue(string summary, string description, string type, string priority, string projectKey)
{
    string key = "";

    try
    {
        var issue = jira.CreateIssue(projectKey);
        issue.Type = type;
        issue.Priority = priority;
        issue.Summary = summary;
        issue.Description = description;

        var jiraIssue = await issue.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (jiraIssue != null)
        {
            key = jiraIssue.Key.ToString();
        }        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }    
    return key;
}
```

I added a breakpoint on the `await issue.SaveChangesAsync()` line and stepped over it. No exception is thrown, so the code continues to wait for the call to finish. Nothing tells me there's an issue.

So I converted the `createIssue` method to non-async:

```
var issue = jira.CreateIssue(projectKey);
issue.Type = type;
issue.Priority = priority;
issue.Summary = summary;
issue.Description = description;

issue.SaveChanges();
```

Here, I get an exception that tells me the actual issue:

> {"Entity with id '' and name 'p - 3' was not found for type 'Atlassian.Jira.IssuePriority'. Available: [10000:p-3,10001:N/A,4:p-4,3:p-2,2:p-1,1:p-0]"}

Is it possible to catch these types of exceptions in the Async methods? Do I need to create a handler or do something else?

Comment: `Task<string> created =...` where are you awaiting that call?

Comment: Hey thanks, that solved it. I had no idea I needed to add await to the call and wrap it in an async method

Comment: You may want to read @StephenCleary async/await introductory [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and any async/await-related blog post on that blog

Comment: Still having trouble with this. I added the 'Task<string> created' call to an async method, and am returning the result of that. From my main method, I call the async wrapper method.. but when it gets there, it doesn't have the result yet

Comment: If I add a breakpoint on the line 'var jiraIssue = await issue.SaveChangesAsync();' it works (because there's a delay). If I remove it, it gets to my main method without the result

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add that new code so I can see what went wrong

Comment: I added the latest edit. My confusion is, I need to call the async method and use the result inside of a method that isn't async (e.g. in this test case, inside a button click), and await can only be used inside of an async method. Must be missing something..

Comment: Thanks @pere57! That was an easier solution than I thought. :) It's working great now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally created a deadlock by blocking your UI thread with `.Result`.

See this [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/) for a discussion.

Change the button handler to async and use await within that. Also, remove `createIssueWrapper` - you don't need it.